# ParentNode returns undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I' trying to get access to the parent of a specific class, however the code seems to only return undefined. My reason for trying to find the child and then the parent is because the identifying attribute belongs to the child and not the parent. In my case I want to remove a video based on the thumbnail.

Here is the relevant code.

manifest.json

```
{
"content_scripts": 
[{
    "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
    "all_frames" : true,
    "js": ["remove_html.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
}],

  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Nms",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "icons": {"128": "img.png"} 
}
```

I have tried both .parentNode and .parentElement

remove_html.js

```
const onMutation = (mutations) => {
  mo.disconnect();
  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (node.id != null) {
        if (node.className == "style-scope ytd-thumbnail"){
          console.log(node);
          console.log("parent",node.parentNode);
      }

        }
    }
  }

  observe();
}

const observe = () => {
  mo.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
  });
}

const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);

observe();
```

the output looks like

```
<ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer class="style-scope ytd-thumbnail" overlay-style="SHORTS" has-icon>…</ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer>flex
parent undefined
```

Comment: you spelled parent incorrect `parantNode`, it should be `parentNode`

Comment: It means this node was added temporarily and then removed by the page. The real node was added inside another element tree, not as a separate node. You can find it by using node.querySelector('.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail')

Comment: I tested your extension and it doesn't reproduce. Has Popeye already solved your problem?

Comment: Popeye did resolve the problem it was a simple spelling mistake